# Is it meaningful to get the centroid of clusters generated by CobWeb clustering algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining

I am using the CobWeb provided by Weka, but there is no function to provide the details of centroids of the clusters. I wonder if it is meaningful to get the centroids? If not, which points should I pick to represent every cluster?

Comment: In most clustering algorithms, clusters just cannot be well represented by a single point...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse But the problem is, there are too many data points as input. How can I pick some of them to do detailed analysis?